# Qual a importancia do branch no versionamento?

Tags: git, branch

- Porque criar branches são importantes no versionamento de um software, ao invés de utilizar apenas o "master" (em aplicações grandes, médias, pequenas ou até mesmo pessoais)?
- Quais vantagens eu tenho em utilizar eles?
- Um versionamento sem eles, pode acarretar em algum "mal"?
- Ter muitos branches poderia virar um problema? Se sim, quanto seria esse muito?

Comment: Versionamento é normalmente feito em tags, que seria um "estado imutável no histórico". Qual sistema de versionamento você usa?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado GIT, no caso seria controle de versão? Me ajuda kkkk .-.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Por si só, branches não são ferramentas de versionamento. Voltarei a isso mais tarde.

Dentro de um processo de desenvolvimento, você pode usar branches de modo a isolar desenvolvimento. Isso permite que você altere uma base de código sem afetar necessariamente toda a parte estável do código. Eu particularmente uso o fluxo de trabalho [gitflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow).

Além do desenvolvimento de funcionalidades de maneira separada, ele também permite ter um branch estável (`master`) e um instável (`develop`). O que quero dizer que branches estáveis e instáveis? Bem, qualquer correção só vai deixar o sistema mais estável (em teoria), então correções nesse sentido não aumentariam a instabilidade do software. Assim, um código de produção após sofrer uma correção, o novo código estará também pronto para ir para produção.

Já uma funcionalidade ou rearquitetura do sistema podem trazer grandes instabilidades no sistema. Aplicar essa mudança de código tem o maior risco de introduzir bugs. Então, caso um código de produção sofra esse tipo de alteração, ele não mais estará pronto para ir para produção.

Veja mais no link que eu postei sobre o [gitflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow).

### Branches e versões

Em diversos projetos você vai encontrar que o repositório inclui branches como `v4.5-stable`, `v4.6-stable` e `v5-unstable`.

Mas qual a função desses branches? Bem, eles não tem função de versionamento, mas de prover estabilidade para cada versão. Isso depende do ciclo de vida de cada lançamento.

Desconsiderando `patches` com correções que precisam ser entregues em quente, só tenho trabalhado em projetos cujo ciclo de vida é de semanas, sendo que a nova versão suplanta totalmente a antiga e não é mais oferecido manutenção a versão anterior. Então eu não tenho muita experiência nesse tipo de desenvolvimento com ciclos de vida longos com sobreposição de versões estáveis, mas posso especular.

Essa separação de branches de manutenção permite que a correção seja feita onde foi detectado o problema e então propagado para as demais versões "mais no futuro", isso tudo sem forçar o cliente a atualizar a versão que está usando. Isso também evita que novas funcionalidades (que trazem instabilidade) sejam inseridas em versões antigas mas mesmo assim oferecendo suporte a elas.

### Por que não usar branches para versionar?

Basicamente porque branches são mutáveis, foram feitos para serem alterados. Versões, não. A versão `v4.5.17` você quer que seja sempre igual a versão `v4.5.17`, não? Se você colocar como branch `v4.5.17`, alguém poderá fazer um commit e alterar o código da versão, sem alterar a string identificadora da versão.

No git, você consegue parte dessa imutabilidade usando tags. Em tese, tags são pontos no histórico código. Não são cabeças que sofrem mudanças, que podem evoluir. São apenas "ponteiros" para um certo momento do código.

## Respondendo pontos específicos

> Porque criar branches são importantes no versionamento de um software, ao invés de utilizar apenas o "master" (em aplicações grandes, médias, pequenas ou até mesmo pessoais)?

Branches separados ajudam na estabilidade do software. Eles também não carregam grande peso de uso, de conceito , de tempo nem de ferramentas.

De toda forma, se você trabalha com git hospedado em algum servidor, você **já está** trabalhando com branches. Na menor das hipóteses, o `master` local e o remoto.

> Quais vantagens eu tenho em utilizar eles?

Estabilidade e isolamento.

> Um versionamento sem eles, pode acarretar em algum "mal"?

Se você for muito disciplinado, não precisaria para o **desenvolvimento**. Mas usar branches no seu fluxo de trabalho ajuda contra falhas humanas eventuais.

> Ter muitos branches poderia virar um problema? Se sim, quanto seria esse muito?

Podem gerar efeitos negativos sim. Por exemplo, um software cliente pode demorar para fazer a exibição dos branches. Ou então dificultar encontrar um branch específico. Já sofri isso com uma configuração no Jenkins, mas conseguiram contornar onde trabalho mudando de um `select box` simples para algo mais interativo com direito a filtros.

Outro problema que pode ocasionar é com colegas de trabalho. Um belo dia um funcionário antigo (que trabalhava antes do git e se dependesse dele continuaria com CVS) reclamou que existiam mais de 10 branches no repositório...

Answer (score 1):

As `BRANCH's` do `GIT` te ajudam a organizar melhor o versionamento, veja bem:

1º: Quando uma pessoa der um `COMMIT` e um `PUSH`, ela pode enviar para a `BRANCH` que ela está utilizando, dessa forma, se caso ela o código que ela fez quebrar alguma coisa, não vai parar o código de todo mundo que está usando a `MASTER` e também não serão todos que vão precisar pegar a versão anterior porque foi quebrada.
Basicamente é isso, as pessoas podem ter como se fosse uma `MASTER` para cada funcionalidade que for criar, dessa forma não commitando direto na `ORIGIN/MASTER`caso seja uma funcionalidade de risco que possa quebrar todo o programa.

2º: Um versionamento sem eles não acarretaria nenhuma mal, só aumentaria daria mais segurança ao código quanto aos `COMMITS`quebrados.

3º: Ter muitas pode carretar um problema de `MERGE`, se caso houver muitas `BRANCH'S` longas, que não estão na `MASTER`, na hora de passar pra lá, pode acarretar vários conflitos, por isso o melhor é fazer a funcionalidade e dar o `COMMIT`e o `PUSH`(Códigos não quebrados) para não acumular muita coisa e dar muitos conflitos na hora do `MERGE`.