# Como trabalhar com release no git?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

O recurso [release](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/releases) do GitHub é um recurso da plataforma ou do próprio Git? Pergunto isso pois não vi este recurso no Bitbucket.

Comment: É da plataforma.

Comment: Não é a resposta para a sua pergunta, mas é uma leitura interessante sobre lançamentos de versão usando Git/Gitflow. Nesta resposta eu discorri um tanto sobre os recursos do Git mesmo para evolução da versão e da prática adotada onde trabalho: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/275914/64969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O recurso release é da plataforma, algo mais alto nível, mas conceitualmente ele se aplica no Git atráves da criação de tags, que são versões estáveis disponibilizadas para os usuários utilizarem. Dessa forma, o que o github chama de release nada mais é do que um recurso da plataforma para disponibilizar tags do Git.

> Referências:
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18506508/whats-the-difference-between-tag-and-release

Comment: Complementando, outras plataformas tem soluções semelhantes a essa do GitHub. No GitLab (e acho que no BitBucket também, mas faz muito tempo que não uso), existe uma seção de tags. Nela, você pode colocar uma espécie de notas de lançamento para cada tag individualmente. Tem uma função muito semelhante à release do GitHub, talvez apenas não tenha a disponibilidade de download de compilados.