# Git - TFS - Formas de se trabalhar com versionamento em equipe

Tags: git, team-foundation-server

Bom dia/tarde/noite!

Hoje onde trabalho, nos temos 3 branches: dev, homologação e produção;

Tudo que todos da equipe fazem, subimos direto na branch de dev, todos testam ai sobe pra homologação, usuarios testam, ai sobe para produção...

Eu gostaria de saber formas de fazer o versionamento e o controle disso, digo eu penso que ter uma branch para cada pessoa da equipe, é mais organizado, tem mais controle de quem esta subindo o que e em que momento do projeto, mas ainda tenho algumas duvidas de como funcionam algumas coisas... Tipo, sou bem leigo com isso, entao pode ser que esteja sendo ignorante no assunto...

Supondo:

`--------- branch Joao

`--------- branch Maria

`--------- branch Principal

Antes de subir qualquer coisa a pessoa precisa puxar da Principal e assim subir a dela?

Apos subir a dela como que faz para jogar para a Principal e é correto eu pensar isso?

Outro ponto é a versão exemplo: v1.0.10, v2.1.100. É possivel fazer isso, subir com um controle na versão? Como posso pesquisar isso, não encontrei nada que eu consiga entender... :/

**EDIT**

Eu criei um repositorio no git para fazer uns testes, criei 2 branches alem da master:

Jose e Maria

Criei um arquivo na master e estou tentando pegar este arquivo na B. Jose e nao estou conseguindo

Consegui pegar o item da master pelo Jose...

**Fim Edit**

Se alguem tiver algum material que explique de um jeito mais simples isso, eu fico muito agradecido...

Comment: https://medium.com/@lariodiniz/tutorial-git-com-git-flow-476ad906c8ae

Comment: eu vi esse aqui tambem, me ajudou bastante https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/275695/qual-a-importancia-do-branch-no-versionamento/275914#275914

Comment: se você nao quiser usar o git-flow que é uma extenção do git você pode usar o conceito, que é criar branches de feature e hotfix.. ;)

Comment: Entendi, eu tava dando uma olhada em tags tbm para versoes (`v1.11`, `v2.33.444`)

Comment: Isso é versionamento semantico, os numeros são na ordem Major.Minor.Version.Build

Comment: https://semver.org/

Comment: https://medium.com/serenata/versionamento-sem%C3%A2ntico-um-passo-al%C3%A9m-do-git-53e466d0f21a

Comment: Obrigado @André me deu um norte muito bom por onde começar

Comment: Como foi respondido nos comentários, acredito que o **Git Flow** vai te ajudar bastante, assim como o **versionamento semântico**. Desse modo, as referências abaixo serão úteis no processo de estudo/implantação: - [Git Flow](https://medium.com/trainingcenter/utilizando-o-fluxo-git-flow-e63d5e0d5e04) - [Versionamento semântico](https://semver.org/lang/pt-BR/) Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Como foi respondido nos comentario e nem foi por vc, eu nao vou dar resposta solucionada por vc kkkkk... O merito não é seu...

Comment: [@LeoHenrique](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/104028/leohenrique), mesmo que não seja você, entenda como exemplo. Se um usuário **negativa** e **evita** de marcar a resposta como a melhor resposta(*a que soluciona o seu problema*), ele acaba informando para todos os outros do fórum que essa resposta **não** foi útil para o caso, **apesar de ter sido**. Para evitar isso, aconselho [@Lucas Dittrich](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/142545/lucas-dittrich) realizar uma [edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/400932/edit) da pergunta e mencionar as fontes ou a autoria necessária.

Comment: O q eu quero dizer: é muito facil eu entrar em varios posts onde a pergunta foi respondida nos comentarios, criar uma resposta e esperar gratificação por isso... Eu acho errado e independente do que é dito pelo forum, eu acho errado ganhar vantagem em cima de outros... É a minha opinião e por este motivo, não vou dar a resposta como a melhor pra ele (ja q nao caso não foi merito dele a resposta)

Comment: É muito mais facil do que estudar o assunto e postar algo de autoria propria...